# Custom events for zend server monitor

Tags: php, reporting, monitoring, zend-server

I have complex SOAP web-service build in PHP with Zend server.

I want to create custom monitoring events in out system.
I are already using "Custom Events" with aggregation hinting but it`s not enough in my case. Events should have different severity and actions take after occurring.

I`m actively using Zend Monitoring for reporting all king of errors. Starting from parsing errors, logical warnings in function to errors got from other systems. It results in really big amount in monitoring in zend server console. Unfortunately all of them are named "Custom Event", so for finding the cause it have to check every Event one by one (also the aggregation hint in not shown in the event list). I can extend the Zend_Log_Writer_ZendMonitor class to log into different place but tham I`m wrighting Zend Monitor :(

I have found that all the events are stored in
/usr/local/zend/etc/events_rules.xml and I plan to add new event there, but can`t find any specifications to this file. What are the possible rules->rule->event-types?

How to handle the problem later in application?
Can the "new" events can be called from inside our system using zend_monitor_custom_event or similar?

Answer (score 1):

You know about the existence of [Zend_Log_Writer_ZendMonitor](http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.log.writers.html)? You can use the Zend_Log component to interact with and log to Zend Server Monitor!

Zend_Log is a generic logging component which seems to cover what you're asking for, namely severity levels.

Zend_Log takes a Zend_Log_Writer instance and in your case you would pass it a Zend_Log_Writer_ZendMonitor instance which is specialized in logging Zend Events to the Zend Server.

Comment: Zend_Log_Writer_ZendMonitor uses the monitor_custom_event() function from the Zend Monitor API. So basically it`s the same I`m having right now.

Basically I wanted to get rid of "Custom Event" and place events like "APi parsing error" and so on. Also the event grouping is not enough.

Comment: Have you concidered extending the class?

Comment: I`m OK with extending it, but don`t see how it solves my problem.

Comment: Well, then I probably just don't know enough about your problem and Zend Server architecture.

Comment: I`m actively using Zend Monitoring for reporting all king of errors. Starting from parsing errors, logical warnings in function to errors got from other systems. It results in really big amount in monitoring in zend server console. Unfortunately all of them are named "Custom Event", so for finding the cause it have to check every Event one by one (also the aggregation hint in not shown in the event list). I can extend the class to log into different place but tham I`m wrighting Zend Monitor :(

Comment: Yes, looking at the writer I see that the possibilities are quite limited and extending it looks hard if the zend server itself doesn't expose an API with more flexibility.

Comment: That`s why I`m planing to extent the xml with server events, but can`t find any docs to it.